# how many elements are there which has order 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

if the number of sylow-3 subgroups of a group of order 96 is 4, how many element are there  which has order 3?

I dont know how to start. why isnt the answer 4?

Comment: How many elements of order three can you see in a single group of order three?

Comment: In a cyclic group of order $3$, say $\langle x\rangle$, it is easy to see that both $x$ and $x^2 = x^{-1}$ have order $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have a group $G$ with $|G| = 96$. If a subgroup of $G$ has order $3^n$ for some $n$, then Lagrange's theorem says that $n$ *must* be either $0$ or $1$. We're told that there are $4$ subgroups of order $3^n$ for the largest possible $n$. Therefore we conclude that $G$ has four subgroups of order $3$. The only element any of them have in common is the identity element $e \in G$, so there are $2\cdot 4 = 8$ other elements in these four groups, and all of those elements must have order $3$.

If there were any *other* elements of order $3$, then such an element would generate a cyclic subgroup of order $3$, but we've accounted for all of those, so there cannot be any other elements of order $3$ than those that are in the $4$ Sylow-3 subgroups.

Comment: Great. Thanks.  So the one should have known the definition of p group